# What files are transformed into markdown tabs on Github and how to add custom files?

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown, readme

I've noticed that some files are turned into Markdown tabs in a GitHub repository, e.g.,

[image]

I wonder what files are turned into tabs, besides `README.md` and `LICENSE`, and how to add custom files to this tab.

Comment: These are files that are ancillary to the repo status. At the time of writing, this the readme, all files identified as license files, the code of conduct, and a security policy.

Comment: "and how to add custom files" it does not appear this is possible.